# How to concatenate efficiently a list of dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a function `crawl` that input an integer and output a dataframe. To concatenate dataframes `df1, df2, df3`, we can use `pandas.concat([df1, df2, df3])`. I would like to ask of there is an efficient way to concatenate `df1,..., df17` without writing a long list `df1 = crawl(1),..., df17 = crawl(17)`.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
pd.concat([crawl(i) for i in range(1,18)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df_list = [crawl(i) for i in range(1,18)]

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```